# Why does my python script hang when using websocket-client and run_forever?

Tags: python, websocket

Sorry in advance for my English, I am french and just doing what I can to be readable. Also, I should tell you that I am blind, so I can't read any screenshots or pictures, only text (including code).

What I am trying to do is make a new engine to create audio games for blind people. I am using [websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) in Python (with the [run_forever](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) method) to connect to a server which I have written in PHP.

Each time I try to start the socket my program gives an error: `pale blue dot doesn't answer`. It seems to cause a problem with my PC too, because my screen reader bugs out and freezes for some time.

I think the issue is with the websocket client because when I comment that out my code runs fine. The stranger thing is, when I watch the server logs, I can see the socket connection correctly established, but my program hangs until I go to the command line of my game and end the task with `ctrl+c`. When I do that, the websocket closes, and my game continues normally (except then I can no longer do anything that needs the websocket... sadly).

My code is split into multiples files. I have included the `network` and `main` files below. Hopefully somebody can help me find a solution to this problem. I usually work with PHP and am very new to Python.

#### Network Code

```python
#global query_sended
#query_sended=lucia.audio_backend.Sound()
#query_sended.load("src/network/sended.ogg")

#global query_receved
#query_receved=lucia.audio_backend.Sound()
#query_receved.load("src/network/receved.ogg")

def on_error(ws,error):
    print(error)
    

def on_close(ws):
    print("closed")
    

def query_send(ws,query,notifiable):
    print(query)
    socket=ws.send(query)
    if(notifiable==True):
        #ddd
        #query_sended.play()
        #ddd
    

#all that is just put hir but not debuged so
#don't think you should take seriously a look on this method... :d :d

def on_message(socket,message):
    #ddd
    from inspect import getmembers
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(getmembers(message))
    #ddd
    
    #query_receved.play()
    interpretor=message.split("&&")
    module=interpretor[0]
    method=interpretor[1]
    param=""
    for i in range(2,len(interpretor)):
        if(param==""):
            param="\""+interpretor[i]+"\""
        else:
            param=param+",\""+interpretor[i]+"\""
            
    print(module+"::"+method+"("+param+")")
    

global socket


def sockopen():
    socket=websocket.WebSocketApp(
        "ws://"+host+port,
        on_message=on_message,
        on_error=on_error,
        on_close=on_close)
    socket.run_forever()
```

#### Main Game Engine

```python
from src import *
#variable used to know where we are in all of possibility in the script time line
wearein=""

#seting the logo of the game
logo=lucia.audio_backend.Sound()
logo.load("src/logo.ogg")



#showing the window of the game and give it a title
client=lucia.show_window("the pale blue dot")

#tel that: the client is in logo mod, and start playing
wearein="logo"
logo.play()

selectmod=True
#ini loop keeping the programe runing
#eccept if the player hit escape
while selectmod==True:
    #even listener of lucia
    lucia.process_events()

    #small code use to kill the game if the player want to exit
    if lucia.key_pressed(pygame.K_ESCAPE):
        logo.stop()
        logoff()

    #if the logo is playing
    if(wearein=="logo"):
        if lucia.key_pressed(pygame.K_RETURN):
            logo.stop()
            modmenu=menu.mod.modmenu()
            if(modmenu=="line"):
                wearein="mainmenu"
                selectmod=False
            if(selectmod=="quite"):
                logoff()
            
        
    

def onlinegame(wearein):
    if lucia.key_pressed(pygame.K_ESCAPE):
        logoff()

    ws=network.sockopen()
#even listener of lucia
    time.sleep(10)
    lucia.process_events()
    #if the player is in main menu
    if(wearein=="mainmenu"):
        client=lucia.show_window("The Pale Blue Dot, menu principal")
        mainmenu=main.mainmenu()

        #test on what value has been returned by the click on a buton of the menu
        if(mainmenu=="register"):
            print("register\n")
            network.query_send(ws,"account&&initplayer&&ID",False)
            wearein="register"
        if(mainmenu=="login"):
            print("connection")
            wearein="login"
        if(mainmenu=="quite"):
            logoff()
        
    

    #if the player come on register
    if(wearein=="register"):
        client=lucia.show_window("the pale blue dot, création d'un compte")
        

onlinegame(wearein)
```